# How to use CLLocationManager [self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading] without GPS?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

If I used

```
[self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

An arrow shows up on status bar.

Does

```
[self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];
```

uses GPS?

If it doesn't, why arrows does show up on statusbar?

Note: I've read the documentation. True heading is available only if location is enabled. What I am thinking is

1. Enable location
2. Get heading once.
3. Compute difference between true heading and magnetic heading.
4. Store that number in a static variable.
5. Disable location.
6. Every time heading is updated, get the magnetic heading, and then add the difference between true heading and magnetic heading.

Another thing I think might work is to set location accuracy to be so wide that it doesn't require GPS at all.

I wonder if it's possible. For example, can we disable location update programatically? As far as I know calling stopUpdatingLocation does not turn off location update (didUpdateToLocation no longer called but an ugly arrow is on status bar).

self.locationManager.locationServicesEnabled=false doesn't work because the property is a class property that's read only. Looks like there is no way to turn off locationServices and yet update heading. I may be wrong. Am I?

Basically I want to help my visitor see direction without excessive GPS.

Comment: This is unrelated to Xcode.

Comment: It's NOT duplicate. I am already aware the answer to that question. This is specifically asking of how to do startUpdatingHeading without GPS

Comment: How is it duplicate? It's totally different question. One ask what object uses GPS this one ask how to startUpdatingHeading without GPS.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, `startUpdatingHeading` uses GPS.

From [CLLocationManager Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html):

> In iOS, a device with the appropriate hardware may also report heading information. When the value in the headingAvailable property is YES, you can use a location manager object to retrieve heading information. To begin the delivery of heading-related events, assign a delegate to the location manager object and call the location manager’s startUpdatingHeading method. If location updates are also enabled, the location manager returns both the true heading and magnetic heading values. If location updates are not enabled, the location manager returns only the magnetic heading value. These features are not available in OS X.

Comment: Deviation from magnetic heading and true heading do not change by much every few kilo meters. Is it possible to get true heading without GPS?

Comment: Not necessarily. To get true heading you need only very rough location coordinate and that doesn't require GPS.

Comment: Is it possible then to disable location updates and compute the true heading from the magnetic heading?

Answer (score -1):

The Location Services are designed to be as efficient as possible, to minimise power consumption and increase battery life.  For example, the API allow you to declare to the service how much measurement accuracy is required, because more accuracy requires more hardware and power.  If you only require low accuracy (eg ~10km) you can simply use the cell towers for location info, which is cheap as the radio is already active.  If you need more accuracy than that (eg. a few km) the hardware might switch to triangulation using WiFi hotspot information, which requires a medium amount of power.  But for the highest accuracy, the system will enable the GPS unit, which consumes much more power.

However, if you only request heading information, the magnetometer alone will be used (provided the hardware supports it; ie. iPhone 4+ IIRC).  The GPS unit will not be enabled in this instance.  As per the [CLLocationManager Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html):

> If location updates are not enabled, the location manager returns only the magnetic heading value.

As for the arrow indicator in the status bar, this is displayed whenever any app uses Location Services.  If you open the built-in Compass app, you'll notice the arrow is displayed there also, even though it only manages heading data.

Using `stopUpdatingLocation` is separate to `stopUpdatingHeading` and will only stop calling your location callback, while also powering down the hardware resources as appropriate.

As for `locationServicesEnabled`, this is set to `YES` if the services are enabled on the device (by the user), which is why the field is read-only.

So, simply call `startUpdatingHeading` and provided you don't call `startUpdatingLocation`, you don't need to worry about the GPS.  The steps you mention are not necessary as CL is already doing the hard work for you.

This information is all covered in the reference:

- [CLLocationManager Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html):